# while vs for statement different behavior

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to understand why this while loop works as expected, but the equivalent (in my mind) for loop does not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs{ "loop-in.txt" };
    if (!ifs)
        perror("can't open input file ");
    vector<int> ys;

    while (true)
    {
        int y;           // get a clean int each time around
        if (!(ifs >> y)) // if it cannot read a int
            break;
        ys.push_back(y); // else: push it into the vector = meaning if(cin>>y)
    }
    cout << "the vector is:\n";
    for (int x : ys)
        cout << x << '\n';
}
```

The loop-in.txt contains random integers: 2 3 4 5 6 1 12 34 3 and the output is as expected:

```
the vector is:
2
3
4
5
6
1
12
34
3
```

But when I make this for loop, the output is strange. See below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs{ "loop-in.txt" };
    if (!ifs)
        error("can't open input file ");
    vector<int> ys;
    for (int y; ifs >> y;)
    {
        if (!(ifs >> y))
            break;
        ys.push_back(y);
    }
    cout << "the vector is:\n";
    for (int x : ys)
        cout << x << '\n';
}
```

The output of the for loop:

```
the vector is:
3
5
1
34
```

I was trying to understand how declaring a variable inside a while loop is different from a for loop when I stumbled upon this problem.
If I delete the if statement, the for loop output is correct.
But I don't understand why it's not working with the if statement when the while loop it's working just fine.
Thanks everyone for taking the time.

Comment: Get your favorite [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and explain to it this for loop, especially, why there are two read operations and what happens to `y` ;)

Comment: You are reading from the file twice `ifs >> y` (one in `for` loop & once in the `if` condition). Remove the one in the `if` condition. As the for loop itself validates, if the read was successful.

Comment: Aside: `std::vector<int> ys(std::istream_iterator<int>(ifs), {});` [You don't have to write either loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int y; ifs >> y;)  // <-- Read here.
{
    if (!(ifs >> y))    // <-- And read here, overwriting read above.
        break;
    ys.push_back(y);    // <-- Only pushes every second one.
}
```

There are *two* reads in every iteration of that loop, the first in the `for` statement, the second in the loop body. That means you'll only be storing half of the values being read.

The equivalent `while` loop would look something like this (maybe not *exactly* but with pretty much a similar effect):

```
while (true)
{
    int y;           // get a clean int each time around
    if (!(ifs >> y)) // if it cannot read a int
        break;
    if (!(ifs >> y)) // if it cannot read a int
        break;
    ys.push_back(y);
}
```

Either stop reading in the `for` statement or stop reading in the body.

Comment: Thank you paxdiablo for your detailed response! it really helped

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you read twice:

```
for (int y; ifs >> y;) // first read from stream here, then the value of y is not used
{
    if (!(ifs >> y)) // second read here
        break;
    ys.push_back(y);
}
```